# How to create new column from CSVWriter in Java

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I have a problem. I want to create a new CSV file from CSVWriter and my whole Array is set into the one cell.

This is my java code:

```
StringWriter s = new StringWriter();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(s, '\t');

        String[] entries = new String[3];
        entries[0] = "Test";
        entries[1] = "Test";
        writer.writeNext(entries);

        writer.close();
        String finalString = s.toString();
        System.out.println(finalString);
```

I get the output like this: `"first"    "second"    "third"`
 and my `CSV` is :
[image]
but I want to be like this:
[image]

Comment: By default, in csv, new column is marked by comma `,`: `"Test","Test"`

Comment: I turned that but I got the problem with  `"` but I solved the problem with `CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(s,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK, the problem is you open the CSV file by **Excel** with default settings.

If you open the CSV file with **Notepad**, it will look like this:

> "Test"    "Test"

And if you still want to open it with **Excel**, you are supposed to open it by following steps:

1. Create a new sheet.
2. Select **Data > From Text File**.
3. Select file (write.csv) to be imported.
4. Click **Finish**.

Comment: Thank you, nice answer.